# Filtering Behat tags by Feature tags and Scenario tags

Tags: php, tags, cucumber, gherkin, behat

Let's say I have 3 feature files with 3 scenarios each.

```
@feature1 @env1

   @scenario1 @method1

   @scenario2 @method2

   @scenario3 @method3
```

```
@feature2 @env1

   @scenario4 @method1

   @scenario5 @method2

   @scenario6 @method3
```

```
@feature3 @env2

   @scenario7 @method1

   @scenario8 @method2

   @scenario9 @method3
```

I want to be able to only run scenarios with @env1 for @method2. if I use "--tags="@env1&&@method2" **ALL** the scenarios with @env1 are run.

Answer (score 0):

either in your runner class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

  @CucumberOptions(

    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    glue = "stepDefinitions",          
    tags="@grup1 or @grup2",                                                             
    dryRun = false
  )
```

Or

instead of && you should use OR